# Is it Possible to Dynamically Launch a Container from another Container in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Here's my scenario,

I want to launch a Job in Kubernetes, the first container that runs will look through a list of custom resources, and launch each of the containers defined in that resource to completion.  I don't know whats in the list ahead of time, I only know when the job is kicked off.

Is this possible?  Can someone point me to something that shows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Kubernetes Client Libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to create any Kubernetes resource from inside your code (given that it has the correct service account of course if RBAC is configured in your cluster).

If you want to run a container to completion, a [Kubernetes Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) would be the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manage **jobs** programmatically using the kubernetes `client-go` project.

Here are some [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples).

To create a job to completion, refer:

- [Job APIs](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/kubernetes/typed/batch/v1/job.go)
- [JobInterface](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/batch/v1#JobInterface)
- [Batch client APIs](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/kubernetes/typed/batch/v1/batch_client.go)

**Custom resources definitions** can be managed using the kubernetes `apiextensions-apiserver` project.

To manage **custom resources definitions**, refer:

- [CRD APIs](https://github.com/kubernetes/apiextensions-apiserver/blob/master/pkg/client/clientset/clientset/typed/apiextensions/v1beta1/customresourcedefinition.go)
- [CRD API tests](https://github.com/kubernetes/apiextensions-apiserver/blob/master/test/integration/basic_test.go)

To create **custom resources**, refer:

- [This link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) has steps to access kubernetes API from inside a pod
- [Example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go)